# Strategy Pattern and Open-Closed Principle Conflict

Tags: oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern, open-closed-principle

I was reading through strategy pattern and was trying to implement it but I have got stuck at deciding the strategy implementation which I feel violates the open-closed principle.

In strategy pattern we code to interface and based on client interaction we will pass in the strategy implementation.

Now if we have bunch of strategies so we need to decide using conditions which strategy the client chooses something like

```
IStrategy str;
    if(stragety1) {
     str = new Strategy1()
    } else if (stragety2) {
     str = new Strategy2()
    } and so on..
str.run()
```

Now as per open-closed principle the above is open to extension **but it is not closed to modification**

If I need to add another strategy(extension) in future I do need to alter this code.

is there a way where this could be avoided or it is how we need to implement strategy pattern ?

Comment: In my experience, the open/closed principle is rarely worthwhile in practice. It espouses a good idea: that the primary implementation has architectural hooks allowing for later customization without addition of new code into the base (only new code into the new custom portion). The main reason this fails in practice is that you almost never know what are the dimensions of variability you will need to account for in the architectural hooks until your code is out in the wild and hits problems of extensibility that nobody planned for.

Comment: Your code looks like a factory pattern to me.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use `if-else` to pick up a strategy. A much mire extensible way will be to have a map/dictionary/registry of strategies, where the key is a string name of the strategy, and the value is a corresponding strategy of a corresponding factory that produces a strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed not closed to modification, but that is due to the way you initialize. You are using a value (enum?) to determine which Strategy subclass should be used. As @bpjoshi points out their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553402/strategy-pattern-and-open-closed-principle-conflict#comment82063603_47553402), this is more of a Factory pattern.

Wikipedia discusses how a Strategy pattern can [support the Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#Strategy_and_open.2Fclosed_principle), instead of hampering it.
In that example, they use a `Car` class with a `Brake` Strategy. Some cars brake with ABS, some don't. Different `Car` subclasses and instances can be given different Strategies for braking.

To get your code closed for modification, you need to select the Strategies differently. You want to select the Strategy in the place where new behavior or subclass is defined. You'd have to refactor your code so that the specific Strategy subclass is applied at the point where the code is extended.

Comment: The wiki article explains the answer I was looking out for.

Comment: its been 3 years.Hope i get a reply.As per wiki example, now the client has to be aware of which class it is going to use, so instead of client specifying the object, isnt passing stretagy in ENUM/String good?I wonder why passing stretagy is bad than making client aware of our classes?

Answer (score 3):

1) You must separate selecting/creating a ***concrete*** strategy from its uses. I. e. use function `selectStrategy`, pass it as (constructor) parameter, etc.

2) There is no way to fully avoid conditional creation, but you can hide it (e. g. using some dictionary for mapping state=>strategy) and/or shift it into another level of the application. The last approach is very powerful and flexible, but depends on the task. In some cases you may put selecting/creating on the same level that uses it. In other cases you may even end up with delegation selecting/creating to the highest/lowest level.

2.1) You can use the [`Registry`](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) pattern and kinda avoid modification of "core" object when adding new strategy's.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is misunderstanding about Closed for Modifications.

In 1988, Mayer said: 
Software that works should when **possible** not be changed when your application is extended with new functionality.

and Rober C. Matrin said:

This definition is obviously dated.
Think about that very carefully. If the behaviors of all the modules in your system could be extended, without modifying them, then you could add new features to that system ***without modifying any old code***. The features would be ***added solely by writing new code***.
https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/12/TheOpenClosedPrinciple.html

Adding some new codes without modifying old codes do not conflict with Open-Closed Principle.

Answer (score -1):

I think the decision you are referring to should be the responsibility of a factory class. The following is some example code:

```
public interface ISalary
{
    decimal Calculate();
}

public class ManagerSalary : ISalary
{
    public decimal Calculate()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class AdminSalary : ISalary
{
    public decimal Calculate()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    private ISalary salary;

    public Employee(ISalary salary)
    {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal CalculateSalary()
    {
        return this.salary.Calculate();
    }
}
```

The Employee class uses the Strategy pattern and follows the Open/Closed principle, i.e. it is open to new strategy types (ISalary implementations) through injection via the constructor, but closed to modification.

The piece that is missing is the code that creates the Employee objects, something like:

```
public enum EmployeeType
{
    Manager,
    Admin
}

public class EmployeeFactory
{
    public Employee CreateEmployee(EmployeeType type)
    {
        if (type == EmployeeType.Manager)
            return new Employee(new ManagerSalary());

        else if (type == EmployeeType.Admin)
            return new Employee(new AdminSalary());

        etc

    }
}
```

This is a very simple factory pattern. There are better ways to do this but this is the simplest way to explain the concept.

Comment: Using `if-else` for picking a strategy is a really bad idea that keeps the code breaking OCP.

Comment: @Igor Soloydenko - Yes I did mention there are better ways to do this. I was just trying to explain why the strategy picking logic is not part of the actual strategy pattern.